# Finding the median without using the function

Tags: excel, vba, median

I'm trying to find the median without using the function.

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim passNum As Integer
Dim temp As Integer
Dim aantal As Integer
Dim n(1 To 50) As Single
Dim p As Integer
Dim j As Single
Dim t As Single
Dim median As Single

aantal = InputBox("how many n variables do you want max 50")

For p = 1 To aantal
    n(p) = InputBox("geef " & aantal & " nummers")
Next

'Rem bubble sort names
For passNum = 1 To aantal - 1
    For i = 1 To aantal - passNum
        If n(i) < n(i + 1) Then
            temp = n(i)
            n(i) = n(i + 1)
            n(i + 1) = temp
        End If
    Next i
Next passNum

'Rem display alphabetized list
For i = 1 To aantal
    Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = n(i)
Next i

'find the median
t = aantal Mod 2

If t > 0 Then
    median = n(aantal + 1) / 2
Else
    median = (n(aantal / 2) + (n(aatnal) / 2) + 1) / 2
End If

Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2) = median

End Sub
```

This won't find the median.

I tried changing n(aantal) for something else. That either gives me the wrong number or nothing.

Comment: You are using ancient data types. An integer, from the 16 bit world,  has a range of -37K to +37K compared to a long of -2gig to +2gig. A single is for first generation FPUs. So `as Long` and `as Double`.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are saying cause in my code i'm already dviding it by 2?

Comment: I tried it it didn't work. maybe it's something with the n(aantal) I think I have to put something different there but I don't know what to put there instead.

Comment: I'm sorry i gave it the elements 2.5.5 and 9 but it came out as 2.5 also have a nice night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
Sub Median()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim aantal As Integer, tmp as double
    ReDim n(0) As Double

100:        
    aantal = InputBox("how many n variables do you want max 50")
    If aantal > 50 Then Goto 100
    
    ReDim n(aantal - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(n)
        n(i) = CDbl(InputBox("Geef nr " & i + 1 & " van " & aantal & " nummers"))
    Next
    
    For i = LBound(n) To UBound(n)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(n)            
            If n(i) > n(j) Then
                tmp = n(j)
                n(j) = n(i)
                n(i) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    m = aantal Mod 2
    ix = ((aantal + m) / 2) - 1
    If (m = 1) Then
        nMedian = n(ix)
    Else
        nMedian = (n(ix) + n(ix + 1)) / 2
    End If
    
    Debug.Print nMedian        
    
End Sub
```